# Show processes and threads as tree view

Tags: process-management

I would like to see a forest display (tree) of all processes and threads.

Like `ps axfwu` but which does not allow to add threads

```
# ps axfwum | less
error: thread display conflicts with forest display
# ps axfwuH | less
error: thread display conflicts with forest display
```

Answer (score 1):

`pstree -Aacutspn` seems to do the trick